# Is possible to create black hole in laboratory?

Tags: black-holes, experimental-physics, mass, estimation

Recently I came to know that black hole are the object which concentrate large amount of mass in small volume. what are the requirements to create this if possible?

Comment: the general belief is a minimum mass of about three times that of our sun.

Comment: I’ll use me garden shed then ...

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Minimum size of black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175397/44126), [Can black holes be created on a miniature scale](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22578/44126).

Comment: @AdrianHoward That's the minimum (core) mass for a black hole to form spontaneously due to gravitation overcoming inter-nucleon repulsion in a neutron star, which is how black holes form in nature today.  Whether that's the *only* way to make a black hole is an open question.

Comment: @rob; true, I should have added "naturally occurring"

Answer (score 0):

I belive that, in theory, all you really need is to compress matter enough so that it shrinks below it's [Schwartzschild radius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius), $R_S=2Gm/c^2$, where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $m$ the mass you want to compress and $c$ the speed of light. For small stuff this is practically impossible to achieve: the [wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) lists that to compress 70 kg to it's Schwartzschild radius, you would need to compress it to the incredible density of $10^{70}$ kg/m$^3$.

However, while black holes might be unachievable on Earth, there is ongoing research into creating [gravitational waves using high intensity lasers](http://ocs.ciemat.es/EPS2019ABS/pdf/P1.4011.pdf), which at least to me sound super cool. The idea there is the famous $E=mc^2$ formula linking mass and energy. By the theory of general relativity, its *energy density* (mass density included) which is responsible for the bending of space time, i.e. gravity. So therefore, we should be able to bend space time enough to detect using incredibly high intensity (energy density) laser here on Earth!