# Minimal mass of (Schwarzchild) black hole

Tags: black-holes, mass, hawking-radiation

After interesting presentation at academic days of emeritus professor of the University of Ljubljana (UL) Andrej Čadež about a notion and detecting of gravitational waves in 2016 an answer arose >what is minimal possible mass for (Schwarzchild) black hole<? Although professor didn't have time left, he just mentioned Hawking radiation, which is higher for BH with lower masses. I haven't done much analysis yet but I guess Planck mass might be a case.

Comment: What is the connection with gravitational waves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How small are the smallest black holes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55091/)